# Python регулярные выражения findAll

Tags: python

Как в findall передать несколько символов? Мне нужно найти количество символов ('\n', '.', ',', 'Пробел') в тексте(Текст в файле air.txt). Но таким образом я могу передать только 1-ин символ. Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать?)

```
import re

common = ('\n')

with open('air.txt', 'r') as file:
    readfile = file.read()
    result = re.findall(common, readfile)
    print('Количество пробелов в файле: ', len(result))

file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать регулярные выражения, а не просто передавать символ для поиска

```
import re

common = r'[\s]|["."]|[","]'

with open('air.txt', 'r') as file:
    readfile = file.read()
    result = re.findall(common, readfile)
    print('Количество пробелов в файле: ', len(result))

file.close()
```

`[\s]|["."]|[","]` - точка и запятые понятно, а `\s` проверяет вхождение любого `whitespace` символа.

`|` - аналог ***или***